# Using wildcard characted in FilterExpression of ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I got some trouble with a FilterExpression. I would like this one takes the **wildcard character beetween two words**. 
I'm gonna better explain :

I have a TextBoxFilter, filled by my search string.
I would like my FilterExpression looks something like that :

```
ODS.FilterExpression = "NAME LIKE '" + TextBoxFilter.Text.Replace(" ", "###") + "' " ;
```

And I would like to replace ### with a certain wildcard characted, but each one ? 
I tried *the percentage symbol %*, the *underscore _*, *the dot .*, *the question mark ?*, but none of these worked.

**My expected result is** : if i search "ONE STRING", my FilterExpression could return all results like "ONE STRING" or "ONE-STRING" or "ONE_STRING" or "ONE*STRING", etc ...

So maybe i can obtain these results by another way ? I would specify that I can't change my SelectMethod.

Hope you get all information to help manage my trouble.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.filterexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The filter expression syntax is the same syntax that is accepted by the [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

and there, it says:

> A wildcard is allowed at the start and end of a pattern, or at the end
>   of a pattern, or at the start of a pattern.

So you can't use the wildcard it that way. You may need to generate an filter expression by code, something like this:

```
string GetFilterExpressionForName(string input) {
    string trimmed = input.Trim();
    return string.Format("NAME LIKE '{0}' OR NAME LIKE '{1}' OR NAME LIKE '{1}'",
                         trimmed,
                         trimmed.Replace(' ', '-'),
                         trimmed.Replace(' ', '_'));
    // TODO: remove/replace wildcards from user input
}
```

It's kind of ugly and you may need to work on it to get what exactly you want, but I don't think you can find a different solution without changing Select.